# Function that shows markers all at once or with a delay

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, ecmascript-6, dom

I have some markers on an image. At some point all these markers are `inactive` (i.e. a class name is added to the element, which hides them) and need to be shown again. This is done by the method `showAll()` of a *class* (it's not a loose function).

This function works like this:

- if no `delay` is given as a parameter, all markers are shown right away
- if `delay` is "true", the markers are shown one after another

This is my implementation:

```
showAll(delay) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.elements.length; ++i) {
        const element = this.elements[i];

        if (delay) {
            element.classList.remove('inactive');
        } else {
            setTimeout(e => {
                element.classList.remove('inactive');
            }, this.delay * i);
        }
    }
}
```

A few words to understand all variables:

- `this.elements` is a list of cached DOM elements
- `this.delay` is simply the delay in `ms`

I'm concerned about the branching and the repetition of `element.classList.remove('inactive');`. However I'm not a fan of this solution:

```
setTimeout(e => {
    element.classList.remove('inactive');
}, delay ? this.delay * i : 0);
```

It seems unecassary to call `setTimout()` anyway.

*Is there any way to improve this code?*

Comment: do you have control over how `showAll()` is called? Would it make sense to wrap that in a `setTimeout()` call?

Comment: Yes, I have total control over all methods in the object. I can add new methods as well, @SamOnela.

Answer (score 2):

#### Make a helper function

One way to simplify this is to use a function to abstract removing the class name from the element. For example, create one like `removeInactiveClassToElement`:

```
removeInactiveClassToElement = (el) =>    el.classList.remove('inactive');
```

Then just call that function when necessary. For the case when calling in setTimeout(), use [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to make a [partially-applied function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions), passing *`null`* as the *thisArg* argument, and then `element` as the first argument.

```
if (delay) {
    setTimeout(removeInactiveClassToElement.bind(null, element), delay * i);
}
else {
    removeInactiveClassToElement(element)
}
```

As you can see above, I switched the logic around so that the delay is added when `delay` has a value, and used that instead of `this.delay`, though if you wanted to set that property on the instance you could do that...

#### Functional approach

One could also use [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of using the `for` statement. While it could slow performance (due to an extra function call on each iteration), it could cut the first couple lines out (e.g. assigning `const element = this.elements[i];`).

```
this.elements.forEach((marker, i) => {
    if (delay) {
        setTimeout(removeInactiveClassToElement.bind(null, marker), delay * i);
    }
    else {
        removeInactiveClassToElement(marker)
    }
});
```

Expand the snippet below for a demonstration, where clicking the image will add marker dots.

```js
//helper functions
addInactiveClassToElement = (el) => el.classList.add('inactive');
removeInactiveClassToElement = (el) =>    el.classList.remove('inactive');
class MarkerList {
  constructor() {
    this.elements = [];
  }
  add(x, y) {
    const marker = document.createElement('div');
    marker.classList.add('marker');
    marker.setAttribute('style', 'left: ' + x + 'px; top: ' + y + 'px;');
    document.body.append(marker);
    this.elements.push(marker);
  }
  hideAll() {
    this.elements.forEach(addInactiveClassToElement);
  }
  showAll(delay) {
    this.elements.forEach((marker, i) => {
      if (delay) {
        setTimeout(removeInactiveClassToElement.bind(null, marker), delay * i);
      }
      else {
        removeInactiveClassToElement(marker)
      }
    });
  }
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var markers = new MarkerList();
  this.addEventListener('click', function(clickEvent) {
    if (clickEvent.target.id == 'hide') {
      markers.hideAll();
    } else if (clickEvent.target.id == 'show') {
      markers.showAll(delay.value);
    } else if (clickEvent.target.id == 'image') {
      markers.add(clickEvent.clientX, clickEvent.clientY);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.marker {
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
}
.inactive {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/eb4f74eab7ebf483efaa9de0371cb5f8?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" width=80 id="image" />
<button id="hide">
  Hide all
</button>
<button id="show">
  Show all
</button>
<div>
 Delay:
 <input id="delay" type="number" value="2000" />
</div>
```

Comment: I prefer `setTimeout(func, 500, arg1)` rather than `setTimeout(func.bind(this, arg1), 500, arg1)` - at least for functions that truly don’t need `this` (I’d also not include those methods in the class, instead adding using a generic `addClass` method)

Comment: good point- that doesn't need to be a method, so I updated it to being a helper function

Answer (score 1):

Use a queue or stack. Place the elements on the queue you want to show and start a timer and keep it running until the queue is empty.

```
// assuming this elements is an array
function showAll(delay) {
    if(this.elements.length > 0){
        const show = element => element.classList.remove('inactive');
        if (!delay) { this.elements.forEach(show) }
        else {
            const queue = [...this.elements];
            const remove = () => {
                show(queue.shift());
                if(queue.length === 0) { clearInterval(handle) }
            }
            const handle = setInterval(remove, delay);
            remove(); // remove the first one now
        }
    }
}
```

But that said there is nothing wrong with how you do it, either way is good. Unless you have a regular main loop as part of an ongoing animation then you do it from there.